# Is there a way to uniquely identify any storage media connected to a Windows PC in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vb.net

I have been searching for a solution to this for weeks.  I'm looking for a way I can uniquely identify any storage media connected to a Windows PC.  Storage media in particular.  This can include internal hard drives, external hard drives, flash drives, SD cards, smartphone storage, etc.  No optical media.

Basically what I want to do, is designate some kind of unique string that is tied to a specific storage device, so any time that storage device is reconnected, regardless of drive letter, it can be auto-detected.

Problems I have run into:

- Not every storage device has a serial number
- When SD cards are accessed via a card reader, the information available available through WMI via the `ManagementObjectSearcher` class is related to the card reader rather than the media

It seems there are 4 main properties that CAN return unique information, but don't always.  `SerialNumber`, `Caption`, `PNPDeviceID`, `Signature`

Surely there must be SOMETHING that Windows does to keep track of storage devices like this.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need 100% uniqueness or could "not supported" devices or a low probability of identity collisions be acceptable, and if so what are those limits.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Well, 100% uniqueness would certainly be ideal if it's possible.  Another suggestion I read while searching around was to put a file on the device with an application-assigned ID that links the software to the storage device.. which is great but might be problematic on devices that don't have write access on the root directory

Comment: This is sounding like an [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  By and large, Windows doesn't *care* what sort of storage device you've attached to it.  Most of that stuff is handled at the device driver layer.  So, what do you *really* want to do, that you think that the solution requires a unique ID?

Answer (score 2):

Can you write to these media? If so, how about creating a file in the root directory containing a GUID and storing a reference to that GUID in your app. As GUIDs and guaranteed unique, you can use this file to uniquely identify the volume.